# No such method exception on dependency

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm

I am using the Realm recyclerview.

```
compile ('com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-recyclerview:0.9.4') {
    exclude module: 'realm-android'
}
```

Together with the normal Realm v2.0.2 ( latest )

The problem is when I run my code now I get

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTable()Lio/realm/internal/TableOrView; in class Lio/realm/RealmResults; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.RealmResults' appears in /data/data/pandapixl.nl.studiebarometer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-2.0.2_65286432d702dab629d2322a66a4c74d2cf9a7e2-classes.dex)
>                                                                                   at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:162)
>                                                                                   at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:129)
>                                                                                   at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:119)

I think its because I am using a realm version that is way higher than the recyclerview supports. Is there a way to run 2 different versions of Realm without getting an error of duplicates in the APK? or is there a way to create a recyclerview myself without using the one I am using now? It doesn't need to be fancy. A basic one will do.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the [`realm/realm-android-adapters`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) project is for.

```
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
```

With `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`.

**EDIT:**

```
    adapter = new RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Dog, DogViewHolder>(getContext(), realm.where(Dog.class).findAllAsync(), true) {
        @Override
        public DogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new DogViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_dog_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DogViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Dog dog = getData().get(position);
            holder.bind(dog);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or

```
    public class DogAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Dog, DogViewHolder> {
        public DogAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Dog> results) {
            super(context, results, true);
        }

        @Override
        public DogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new DogViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_dog_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DogViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Dog dog = getData().get(position);
            holder.bind(dog);
        }
    };
```

Comment: do you have an example of how to use it?

Comment: yeah, although it's fairly simple

Comment: So I don't have to make a custom adapter class? this is all it?

Comment: Well nobody stops you from explicitly creating a `public class DogAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Dog, DogViewHolder> { /*...*/ super(context, results, true); }` class if you want, but it's _not necessary_.

Comment: Well I have made one, but not sure if its entirely correct I am getting a error on the super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate) part. Can you take a look at it? I put it in a pastebin. http://pastebin.com/z7ixSsGa :) thanks for your help so far

Comment: ...Use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, and not `RealmBaseAdapter`

Comment: Added example of making a class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126273/discussion-between-reshad-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: Where does the GradeViewHolder coming from?

Comment: That's just a viewholder like this one https://github.com/Zhuinden/rx-realm-recyclerview-experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/rxrealm/path/dog/DogViewHolder.java